# Laravel auth::sanctum middleware not working for API routes

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware, laravel-routing, laravel-sanctum

I am getting the error `InvalidArgumentException: Auth guard [auth] is not defined.`  with the below given code.I understood this error is because I have added `auth` in the `guards` array of `config/sanctum.php` . But I am not understanding what else is to be given there instead of `auth`.

My actual requirement is to get the logged in user's id in my API by using the `sanctum` middleware for authentication. It currently returns `null` for the line of code in controller.

Does anyone know what all fixes shall i make in this context? Any help is appreciated.

**Controller**

```
 dd(auth()->user());
```

**routes/api.php**

```
Route::post('login', [UserController::class, 'Login'])->name('login');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'],function () {
   Route::group(['middleware' => ['user','auth:sanctum']], function () {
     Route::post('send-msg', [ChatController::class, 'store'])->name('send-msg');
     });
   }
);
```

**Kernal.php**

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
        'api' => [
             \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'user' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthUser::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
```

**config/sanctum.php**

```
'guard' => ['web','auth'],
```

**config/auth.php**

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
    ],
```

**Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

auth() is belong to laravel web authentication which maintains state using session storage and cookies, not sanctum it self.
what authentication method your app is using?

you should just use laravel web authentication if you are developing laravel web.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\User;
use Validator;
class AuthController extends Controller
{
public function register(Request $request)
  {
      $request->validate([
          'name' => 'required|string',
          'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users',
          'password' => 'required|string|',
          'c_password'=>'required|same:password',
      ]);

      $user = new User([
          'name' => $request->name,
          'email' => $request->email,
          'password' => bcrypt($request->password)
      ]);

      if($user->save()){
          return response()->json([
              'message' => 'Successfully created user!'
          ], 201);
      }else{
          return response()->json(['error'=>'Provide proper details']);
      }
    }
  }
public function login(Request $request)
{
  $request->validate([
    'email' => 'required|string|email',
    'password' => 'required|string',
    'remember_me' => 'boolean'
  ]);

  $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
  if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
  {
    return response()->json([
    'message' => 'Unauthorized'
    ], 401);
  }

  $user = $request->user();
  $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
  $token = $tokenResult->plainTextToken;


  return response()->json([
    'access_token' => $token,
    'token_type' => 'Bearer',
  ]);
}

public function user(Request $request)
{
  $user = Auth::user();
  return response()->json($user);
}

}
```

Your User Model should you HasApi Trait

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
  use HasApiTokens;
}
```

Then to guard your route

```
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
Route::group([
  'prefix' => 'auth'
], function () {
  Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
  Route::post('register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);

  Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'auth:sanctum'
  ], function () {
    Route::get('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::get('user', [AuthController::class, 'user']);
  });
});
```

Comment: I am developing API s for mobile app for not a website. And i wanted to use sanctum  for authentication. I have clearly mentioned that in original question. can you tell me what all changes shall i make in the codes of above files to achieve that?

Comment: make a new AuthController.
let me show you an example. a moment.

Comment: ok.thanks in advance. one more thing : my big error is in `config/sanctum.php`.I have said it in the first line of question. Please see it. What change shall i make there?

Comment: Sanctum API token, 
So to guard your route, make sure your model using using hasapi traing
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
  use HasApiTokens;
}

Comment: I have added that trait in model. My issue i told you - it is in config/ sanctum.php.  Some thing i have defined wrong in those configuration files

Comment: for this, InvalidArgumentException: Auth guard [auth] is not defined. have you try ?
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache

Comment: Within config/sanctum.php there is set values being returned which comes okay there is no need to reconfigure anything. Why don't you begin afresh installing laravel sanctum folllowing this documentation form laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum, Again see if you're checking the ID correctly try this: "auth()->user()->id"

Comment: Within **config/auth.php** rectify the value for **driver** within api to "token" then clear cache and run server and test again you should be fine.